# PowerShell script string interpolation with named parameters is not working

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

I have the following function (I just paste it into the command line):

```
function Test ($url, $interface, $method)
{
   Write-Host "http://$url/$interface/$method"
}
```

I then call it:

```
Test("localhost:90", "IService", "TestMethod")
```

I get:

```
http://localhost:90 IService TestMethod//
```

I expect to get:

```
http://localhost:90/IService/TestMethod
```

The same thing happens if I first set the result to a variable:

```
$res = "http://$url/$interface/$method"
Write-Host $res
```

I also don't think it's due to `Write-Host`, since I get the same error if I pass this string into .NET objects.

It completely confuses me that this *works* if I just define each variable. So, it's something to do with the fact that these are function parameters. I can do this from the command line:

```
PS C:\> $url = "localhost:90"
PS C:\> $interface = "IService"
PS C:\> $method = "TestMethod"
PS C:\> Write-Host "http://$url/$interface/$method"
http://localhost:90/IService/TestMethod
PS C:\>
```

Am I doing something silly, or is there another way to do string interpolation in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't doing anything silly, but you are conflating PowerShell with something like Python.

When I do:

```
Function Count-Args
{
    $args.count
}

Count-args($var1, $var2, $var3)
```

I get a count of 1, and all three variables you put into `()` are cast as a single array to `$args`.

Just change the way you call the function to the `test mysite myinterface mymethod`. Note the [ss64 site advice](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-functions.html).

```
Don't add brackets around the function parameters:

$result = Add-Numbers (5, 10) --Wrong!
$result = Add-Numbers 5 10    --Right
```

Comment: You don't even need to make a param block, if you keep your original function and just space the arguments like in the bottom of my example it'll work.

Comment: Confirmed.  It's always the basic things like this that get me in PowerShell.

Comment: You'd probably get a lot of benefit out of an intro to Powershell book, all you have here is a common practices issue.  PowerShell.org has a lot of nice free ebooks for learning PS.